# Cannot access property $id on mixed

Tags: php, laravel

$subject_code contains mixed numbers and characters

Code working properly but phpstan showing error

```
$subject = Subject::whereSubjectCode($subject_code)->first();

return SubjectCollection::create([

 'subject_id' => $subject->id,

]);
```

Comment: Is that the full proper error?

Comment: Yes sir @aynber

Comment: You are missing the closing bracket for the array in your create function?

Comment: I am not familiar with phpstan, but https://github.com/nunomaduro/larastan/issues/103  might be of some help.

Comment: Use an `@var` annotation on the variable. PHPStan can’t figure out what the variable is at this point, so you need to give it a hint.

Comment: I Added /** @var object */ it works